# Can I get project path or properties from Roslyn analyzer analysis context?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm implementing a Roslyn analyzer and I want to take different action based on how some properties are set within the csproj.

Currently I'm accomplishing this by setting "AdditionalFiles" node in a props file imported with the analyzer. This points to the .csproj and then I manually xml-parse the project file looking for the properties I care about.

```
    <ItemGroup>
      <AdditionalFiles Include="$(ProjectPath)" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

```
        private void AnalyzeAdditionalFiles(CompilationStartAnalysisContext context)
        {
            ICompilationStartAnalysisContextWrapper wrappedContext = this.compilationStartAnalysisContextWrapperFactory.Create(context);

            if (wrappedContext.GetAdditionalTexts()
                              .Any(addtionalFile => <xml parse and validate csproj>))
            {
                context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(this.AnalyzeSyntaxNode, PossibleSyntaxKinds);
            }
        }
```

I've been told there may be a first-class supported way to do one or both of these actions without requiring what feels like hacky versions of:

- Find the path to the csproj
- Fetch properties from the csproj

Is this possible? Ideally I'd be looking for the moral equivalent of

```
AnalysisContext.Project.Properties["MyCustomProp"]
```

Comment: Did you try 
`context.Options.AditionalFiles` collection of `AdditionalText` what has property `Path` or method `GetText()` ?
Or just `context.Project.Documents `

Answer (score 4):

It's now possible to retrieve some project properties, starting with VS 16.7 preview3. It's based around the new csproj tag `CompilerVisibleProperty`.
You can find more information on the [source generator cookbook](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#consume-msbuild-properties-and-metadata), but here's a quick example.

First, in your csproj file, you declare your property, and allow the analyzer to access it:

```xml
<!-- declare the property you want to access in your analyzer -->
<PropertyGroup>
    <MyCustomProp>Value from csproj</MyCustomProp>
</PropertyGroup>

<!-- explicitly allow the analyzer to access that variable -->
<ItemGroup>
    <CompilerVisibleProperty Include="MyCustomProp" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You can then access this variable from any analyzer context, via the [AnalyzerConfigOptionsProvider.GlobalOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.diagnostics.analyzerconfigoptionsprovider.globaloptions?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.0.1). For example:

```cs
private static void CompilationStart(CompilationStartAnalysisContext context)
{
  // retrieve the global analyzer options 
  var globalOptions = context.Options.AnalyzerConfigOptionsProvider.GlobalOptions;

  // retrieve the actual build property 
  // -> wanted property name prefixed with "build_property."
  string myCustomProp = null;
  if (!globalOptions.TryGetValue("build_property.MyCustomProp", out myCustomProp))
        myCustomProp = "Default";
}
```

Nuget packages used for this example:

- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers 3.3.3
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 4.0.1